# Android List widget question

Tags: android, user-interface, widget

I have been googling for a couple days now searching for a sortable list widget similar to the one provided by stock android music app.  What I would like is ability to sort a list similar to how you can sort your music playlist.  I am coming to the conclusion that I am obviously not using the proper keyword to find my answer.  Any help would rule.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is the same code](http://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-touchlist) from the music player app, pulled out into a semi-reusable component.